# show unmatched record from table?

Tags: mysql, select

I'm trying write a query to find records which don't have a matching record in another table.

this my design tabel

```
table 1 
    id | fid | phone | name
    1a | 1b  | 201   | dave
    1a | 2c  | 012   | albert
    1a | 2z  | 909   | huerem
    3a | 2f  | 919   | merria
    2a | 9z  | 209   | gonma

table 2 
    id | phone 
    4x | 121
    2c | 121
    1d | 009
    3b | 889
    5a | 121
```

i want to show record from table2 where phone=121 that `table2.id` **not exist** in `table1.fid`,so the result will be 4x,5a

any query to do this?

Comment: Table 1 and table 2 appear to be mutually exclusive based on the `phone` field.  Maybe you can update your sample data to more clearly illustrate your question?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen read the question again, its pretty clear `i want to show record from table2 where phone=121 that table2.id not exist in table1.fid,so the result will be 4x,5a`

Comment: @JohnRuddell I'm sure your query is what he wants, but his original data but in this case the whole of table 2 will get returned.  This is a bad sample data set.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, maybe this sample is bad, but its just sample, still any related table in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so left join the table and specify null

```
select t.*
from table2 t
left join table1 tt on t.id = tt.fid
where tt.fid is null and t.phone = 121
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5e630e/1)

Comment: i try use left join before I ask here and not work properly, your answer really good, the result show what i want.